# I wiped my hard drive and installed Linux on my MacBook Pro. Can I put OS X back on my computer for free?

Tags: macos

Can I get a free copy of OS X from my Macbook Pro's serial number or something? I'd like to reinstall macOS on this computer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of macOS is included with the Mac. You can reinstall using either Internet Recovery or a bootable USB installer.

Apple's brief description is [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).

Depending on the state of your boot disk, you will probably not be able to use simple Recovery Mode (Command-R when powering on), but will need one of the choices under "Other macOS installation options". Easiest may be Internet Recovery (command-option-R when powering on).

Using a bootable USB installer requires another Mac to download macOS and to create the bootable USB.